# What is the actual value of cos 90?

Tags: objective-c, math, trigonometry

I am getting a wrong value when I do this

```
NSLog(@"cos 90 is %.f", cos(90.0));
```

The answer I get is -0. When I did a Google search, this is what I got:

> cos(90 radians) = -0.448073616.

However the answer that my Casio calculator gives me is 0, and also when I was growing up as a kid, `cos 90 = 0` was drilled into my brain.

Who is right, is it ObjC, Google, or my Casio calculator?

Comment: When cos 90 = 0, it's 90 degrees, not 90 radians. Your calculator must be in degrees mode.

Comment: Dare I say this is wildly off topic?

Comment: It's Objective C because he's trying to do this via "`NSLog`", but the same problem would happen if he were using "`printf`".

Comment: @mydogisbox it is not off topic because it is something I am seeing in my code.

Comment: @tawheed Then you asked the wrong question.  Your actual question was something like: "Am I using this API correctly"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It all depends on whether you're measuring in degrees or radians.

90 degrees (pi/2 radians) has, as you said, a cosine of 0. That's pretty much by definition.

90 radians is 14.323945 times around a circle. The only part that matters is the remainder: 0.323945 of a circle, or 2.035406 radians. The cosine of that is (as you already found) -0.448074. This one isn't a definition, so the real numbers are irrational, and what I've quoted are only approximations.

Answer (score 2):

Change that line to:

```
NSLog(@"cos 90 is %0.5f", cos(90.0));
```

or

```
NSLog(@"cos 90 is %f", cos(90.0));
```

And you'll have much happier results.

The "`%.f`" in your format string is confusing NSLog.

Comment: What about degrees versus radians?  Are you still suggesting that passing the argument 90.0 to the function will have the desired result?